# My code against LocalDB works but I can't see the database anywhere

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, localdb

I have a simple website that uses EF Code First and LocalDB. This is in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

My website works fine, PowerShell commands like `Update-Database` and `Add-Migration` work fine, however, I cannot see the database anywhere inside Visual Studio. Not in SQL Server Object Explorer, not in Server Explorer (when I try to connect to "MyContext" database on the `(localdb)\v11` server, the dialog tells me that there is no such db there).

[image: MyContext misssing]

I am confused. Where is my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one property define - Initial Catalog

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=YourDbName;Integrated Security=True;
```

Comment: That was it. I was confused by the fact that this parameter is usually not mentioned when discussing LocalDB connection string, see e.g. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: But where DB was all the time??

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name of the database within your connection string, like this:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=YourDbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

or, in the more typical format (since it's the format generated by [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=YourDbName;Integrated Security=True;
```

It's worth noting for seasoned developers that the use of "SSPI" is [encouraged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx) :

> When `false`, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, and `sspi` (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to `true`.

And also that [the Connection String docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN are quite exhaustive if you're wondering what keys are valid for all providers, and also [which keys are valid for the SqlClient provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx).